# UIAutomation testing to detect if a button is set as default

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

I've been googling around for an answer to this, but not found anything so far.

I'm writing a number of UIAutomation tests for a WPF application, but I can't seem to determine if a button is set as default.

For example, say you have a number of textboxes on a form. There is a find button that is set as the default button (i.e. you will be invoked when you press ENTER) when the the address textbox has focus.

The trouble I'm having is how to determine if the IsDefault is true when the address field has focus, and false when the address does not have focus.

There doesn't seem to be a way to evaluate this property from what I can see.

So, any help in figuring this out would really help.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Found a workaround. You can check the AccessKey to see if has changed to \r

Comment: **Looks like this is still an issue**. The AccessKey is updated, sometimes, but not during a single test. Using UISpy, the AccessKey is only refreshed after selecting another node, then selecting the button node again. Even clicking Refresh on the node will not update it. Also, the AutomationElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle always returns 0, which makes it difficult to use the Win32 API to get the style. So, any help would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can monitor the "TextPattern.TextSelectionChangedEvent" if the TextBox is a standard WPF Control "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox".

The details in the MSDN (TextPattern.TextSelectionChangedEvent) -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.textpattern.textselectionchangedevent.aspx

You can check and monitor this events via UISpy: i. Select the target edit control in the Tree. ii. Select the menu "Events" -> "Configure" (select the scope and events) iii. select the menu "Events" -> "Start"

The UISpy will trace the event to the output panel when there are some events happened on the EditBox.

- If these edit box is not the standard WPF Control "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox".
  You can try to check the "ControlPatterns" in the UISpy and check the related info of the patterns.